# Download installer for old version of Git

Tags: windows-7, installation, git

I need to install Git on an isolated computer which is not connected to the internet. This computer is extremely controlled, with all installations requiring approval and admin privileges (not me). The most recent version of git which is approved for the system is 2.3.4.

Normally, I would just go to the website, download the single-file installer and bring it over to the computer to be installed. However, the [current downloadable version of Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) is 2.5.1. I see that there is a link to [older versions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/), but they are all tarred folders of source code, which require other software (and therefore approvals) to compile and install git on Windows.

My question: Since the older versions were the current versions at one point, they should have all had executable installers as well. Are these installers of older versions kept anywhere that are available to download? Or can anyone suggest an easier way to install an older version of git on Windows without being able to connect said computer to the internet?

Comment: Came here looking for same answer. AFAIK, there weren't any (publicly released) builds for windows from version 1.8 to 2.5. So no wonder you won't find 2.3. However I can't even find 1.8 now, which is what I'll settle for. Anyone have any idea where could I find the last publicly released windows build which was 1.8??

Comment: nm, found it https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Where can I get an older version of `git` for Windows?

You're right, the download page links to old *source* releases on [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/).

However, the [GitHub page for `git-for-windows`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/) provides download links, where you can get [2.3.4 portable dev preview, for example](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.3.4.windows.2).

*(note, I don't see the final release of `2.3.4`, but as per Ramhound's comment there is no guarantee this was released; what is presented should hopefully fit your needs)*

Comment: There isn't a guarantee that there was ever a final version released.

Comment: @Ramhound ah, thanks for the info- will edit answer to reflect that :)

Answer (score 0):

To summarise, if I've understood and researched correctly:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/ has tarred folders of source codes for ALL versions of Git that have been developed. However, compiling and installing source code on Windows requires third party tools and is a development quagmire.

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases?after=v2.5.2.windows.1 has full executable Git for Windows installers from version 2.5 onwards. It also has release candidate version installers for v2.4 and preview installers for v2.3. Earlier versions than v2.3 are all stored as zip folders.

It is not clear whether earlier versions than v2.5 were actually released as full publicly released versions, though I suspect that installers of v2.2 and prior iterations (the ones stored as zips) have been discarded from the archives due to obsolescence.

github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases which laggingreflex suggested above, has preview version installers of msysGit back to v1.7. However, I'd caution that msysGit and Git for Windows are *not* the same thing - msysGit installer provides the development environment and resources to compile Git yourself, and Git for Windows installer is the ready-to-use package pre-compiled for Windows.